# Получить значение по ключу из словаря

Tags: python, list, словари

Есть список со словарём,  в котором два ключа со значением. Мне нужно вытащить значение по ключу из этого словаря. Однако, методы, которые обычно работают со словарём не работают, потому что это список.

```
k = 0
goods = {
    'лампа': '12345',
    'стол': '23456',
    'диван': '34567',
    'стул': '45678'
}
store = {
    '12345': [
        {'quantity': 27, 'price': 42},
    ],
    '23456': [
        {'quantity': 22, 'price': 510},
        {'quantity': 32, 'price': 520},
    ],
    '34567': [
        {'quantity': 2, 'price': 1200},
        {'quantity': 1, 'price': 1150},
    ],
    '45678': [
        {'quantity': 50, 'price': 100},
        {'quantity': 12, 'price': 95},
        {'quantity': 43, 'price': 97},
    ],
}
good = 'лампа' #input('Введите наименование товара')
if good in goods:
    k = goods[good]
else:
    print('Ошибка - Наименование товара введено неверно.')
v = store[k]
s = v.count{}
```

Мне нужно вытащить 'quantity' и 'price', чтобы потом перемножить их.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

так подойдет?

```
if good in goods:
    key = goods[good]
    object = store[key]

    res = sum(element['quantity'] * element['price'] for element in object)
    print(res)
```

Comment: как я понял это захватит только одну строчку {'quantity': 00, 'price': 00}, и если с лампой проблем нет, то как быть с другими где может быть несколько видов?

Comment: а я не понял тогда задачу - вам надо подсчитать итоговую сумму для ВСЕХ товаров из массива goods?

Comment: Если нужны и ключи и значения, то почему не перебирать `goods.items()`? Если нужны только значения, почему не перебирать `goods.values()`?

Comment: В базе данных магазина вся необходимая информация по товарам делится на два словаря: первый отвечает за коды товаров, второй — за списки количества разнообразных товаров на складе. аждая запись второго словаря отображает, сколько и по какой цене закупалось товаров (цена указана за одну штуку).

Напишите программу, которая рассчитывает, на какую сумму лежит каждого товара на складе, и выводит эту информацию на экран.

Результат работы программы:

Лампа — 27 штук, стоимость 1134 рубля

Стол — 54 штуки, стоимость 27 860 рублей

Диван — 3 штуки, стоимость 3550 рублей

Стул — 105 шт...

Comment: Вот что я сделал: https://pastebin.com/5ZP46SXh